# MongooseJS - how to push the right format?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create the data in this format:

```
{
    "weather": {
        "dailysummary": [...],
        "created_on": "2016-10-27 11:11:11",
        "addedOnLastHour": false
    }
}
```

but why moongoose keeps giving me this format:

```
{
    "weather": [
        {
        "dailysummary": [...],
        "created_on": "2016-10-27 11:11:11",
        "addedOnLastHour": false
        }
    ]
}
```

My code:

```
var updateQuery = {};
var weather = {};
weather.dailysummary = [];
weather.created_on = '2016-10-27 11:11:11';
weather.addedOnLastHour = false;

// Insert date data.
updateQuery["weather"] = weather;

stream.update({
    $push: updateQuery
}, function(err, streamID) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }
    // success
});
```

What have I done wrong? Any ideas?

My model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

// Declare schema
var streamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    weather: {
        type: Object
    },
});

streamSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

// Export schema
// Model.paginate()
mongoose.model("Stream", streamSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **$set** operator instead of **$push**

try this:

```
stream.update({
    $set: updateQuery
}, function(err, streamID) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }
    // success
});
```

Comment: i m glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The **$push** seems to be the problem maker. It is used to push objects to array datatype attribute. Hence your are getting an array of weather. Below is an example snippet for update in mongoose.

```
Contact.update({_id: contact.id}, weatherObject, {}, function() {});
```

Here:

**Contact** -> model

**Where Clause** -> {_id: contact.id}

**weatherObject** -> Update data